# exception occurred when using GAE/J and Google Cloud SQL with multiple project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

following exception occured.

```
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:33)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unable to open connection to the instance: project-A:dba
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket.<init>(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.connect(GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.java:81)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cloudsql/project-A:dba(No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile...(length 8379)
```

I have two GAE/J project and both refer same google cloud sql instance.
ex)

- project-A(gae/j) use project-A:dba(cloudsql)
- project-B(gae/j) use project-A:dba(cloudsql)

such exception occured in project-B.

```
db connection setting is following.
////(in project-B's java file)//////
String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://"+ "project-B" + ":db/db1";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
////
```

this is bug? or any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If the Cloud SQL instance is the same for both projects, then the "project X" used as a qualifier of the instance, must be the same for both applications. This is the project name under which the Cloud SQL instance was created.

The DB host is [built in Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database) as "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/"

According to your example, it would be "project-A:db/".

Don't forget to authorize your project-B app to access the Cloud SQL instance.